# Etiquetas HTML dentro de tablas en MySQL ¿Como mostar la tabla adecuadamente en Angular?

Tags: html, mysql, angular

Buenos días y muchas gracias de antemano

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Angular 7 conectándome a una Base de datos SQL que dentro de algunos parrafos tiene etiquetas HTML como ejemplo:

La tabla "Capitulos" contiene dentro de la columna "contenido" algo como:

```
<div class="paragraph"><a href="https://82581276-122113110919299314.preview.editmysite.com/editor/main.php#"><strong><font color="#2a2a2a">Cap&iacute;tulo 2: El Pueblo Buey Verde</font></strong></a><br /><br />&#8203;El hogar de Han Li era considerado una peque&ntilde;a ciudad. Pero en realidad era solo un pueblo grande llamado Ciudad Buey Verde.
```

Por supuesto es un párrafo larguísimo y tiene las etiquetas bien cerradas.

el parrafo es mostrado a traves de algo como {{capitulo.contenido}}

El punto es: Me estoy trayendo toda la información de la base de datos y es transformada a JSON para mostrarla a través de mi aplicación de Anuglar pero estos parrafos con etiquetas adentro no tengo idea de como hacer que la Aplicación interprete esas etiquetas

No es una opción sacarlas de la DB SQL ya que son mas de 17.000 entradas que tienen estos escenarios.

PD: tuve que poner el contenido de la tabla con el deslizado ese ya que esta pagina interpreta el código perfectamente :´)

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar poperty binding con la propiedad `innerHTML` de un div:

```
<div [innerHTML]="capitulo.contenido"></div>
```

También se puede usar interpolación:

```
<div innerHTML="{{ capitulo.contenido }}"></div>
```

Más información en la documentación oficial de Angular: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation

Comment: Si es correcto funciono perfecto ¡Que facil!

Te debo una cerveza

Mil gracias!!!

Comment: De nada, con que la marques como respuesta aceptada ya vale :)